# How did typescript find d.ts file when it is not mentioned in the config

Tags: typescript

So I have a typescript file where I import an mdx file

```
import mdx from "./Layout.mdx";
```

The compiler complains about it so after researching I find [this page](https://mdxjs.com/advanced/typescript). It tells me

> If you’re getting errors from TypeScript related to imports with an
> *.mdx extension, create an mdx.d.ts file in your types directory and include it inside your tsconfig.json.

```
// types/mdx.d.ts
declare module '*.mdx' {
  let MDXComponent: (props: any) => JSX.Element
  export default MDXComponent
}
```

I created that file. Now my folder structure looks like

```
Root
-types
--mdx.d.ts
-src
--My tsx files
```

Afterwards my compiler doesn't complain anymore about the import. What I don't understand is how did it even find the d.ts I dropped into the types folder. My tsconfig.json is like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "storybook-static",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

I don't even reference the types folder at all.

**EDIT**: Clarification - the complaint was from Visual Code IDE. It had a red squiggly line under the import which later went away after dropping in the d.ts to the types folder.

**EDIT2:** Link to [package.json](https://gitlab.com/joshua.augustinus/storybook-sass/-/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: You are using node module resolution. Are you sure it's not being referenced from your package.json?

Comment: I don't think so. Here's a link to my package.json: https://gitlab.com/joshua.augustinus/storybook-sass/-/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 2):

Typescript does not include the types directory by default and hence it did not find this d.ts file. What it does include in compilation, is already explained in an up to date fashion here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Project_Files_0

Careful though, because these included files are only the starting point.
If you would import something in one of the included files from some location, then that gets included as well, even if it is in an "exluded directory".

This also implies that those excludes in your tsconfig.json [`"node_modules", "build", "storybook-static"`] are not making any difference since these are already "not included" by `"include": ["src/**/*"]`.

To back up my answer above, I checked out [your project](https://gitlab.com/joshua.augustinus/storybook-sass), did an `npm ci` and tried compiling with `npx tsc` and then tried some things.

My conclusion is that typescript does not include this `types/mdx.d.ts` file in the compilation but that the compilation is fine without it.
I say that because if I remove the file, or I put some syntactic error in it, it all makes no difference, the compilation still succeeds without error.

So what you are seeing/saw is probably an IDE thing [indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63662897/4962858) or for example some cache issue with the compilation that you had.

If this still does not match what you are seeing, then I would ask the following questions:

- Have you checked that your IDE uses the typescript from your node
  modules and not some globally installed version instead?
- Have you
  tried doing a fresh checkout of your project and then doing the
  typescript compilation with `npx tsc` and then `npx tsc` again after
  removing `types/mdx.d.ts`?

Answer (score 1):

> Afterwards my compiler doesn't complain anymore about the import

Your IDE might not be complaining (IDEs add files that are open to the compilation context to provide a nicer dev experience) but the compiler still will. You can run the compiler by

```
tsc -p ./tsconfig.json
```